# Animation with LaTeX Tables

Tags: tables, animations

I am trying to create an image in LaTeX that shows a table auto-filling itself, such as the four tables shown below. I've seen some posts about animating pictures, but I haven't seen anything about compiling "slides" together into an image. The four slides are below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & \\
\hline
 & 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
3 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces the tables, but I don't know how to make them into one image. How do I combine them?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you could facilitate the animate-package (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf 5 - The user interface -- Quote regarding the animateline: Even ordinary textual material may be animated in this way.)

Comment: You want to make an animated GIF?

Comment: @Werner Yes I do.

Comment: @Eridan: You can use the following as a guide: [Animations in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152358/5764) I typically use ImageMagick's `convert` to make an animated GIF out of a multi-page PDF.

Comment: Thanks, @Werner I'd seen that page, but it looked like it was tikzpicture-specific. Now I see it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code produces a table that fills itself:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
1 &{\color{white}2} \\\hline
 & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\newframe
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
1 & 2\\\hline
 & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\newframe
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
1 & 2\\\hline
3 & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\newframe
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
1 & 2\\\hline
3 & 4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

I took the liberty to also add the xcolor package and adding a white 2 to the first table. That way the table doesn't change it's form. The only way I was able to see the animation was the usage of the Adobe PDF reader.

Frames:
[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]
[image: Fourth]

Cheers

Comment: If you want the table to grow on click, put option `step` to the `animateinline` environment.