# Obtain an animated PDF from an animated SVG

Tags: graphics, pdf, animations, animate, svg

I have read [Animations in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152358/animations-in-latex), but my question (I think) is different.

I have an SVG animated file and I want to create the same animation in LaTeX, without rewriting the code.
An example is [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Transistor_Bistable_interactive_animated-en.svg) (created with Inskape). I have tried to obtain the PDF from Inkscape, but in this way I lost the animation.

Apologize if this question is a duplicate.

**EDIT**

I am looking for a LaTeX code. ;-)

Comment: +1 I didn't know that SVG supported animations. I couldn't see or edit the animation with Inkscape by the way.  I opened the SVG in an editor, and it says "inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939". I also found some It has some "<animatation>" XML tags. It is possible that this is not really SVG but some XML hack for web browsers because I see it is also interactive.

Comment: I think what you can do is open with inkscape, save a set of SVG frame by frame (move the yellow arrow manually) in PDF and use the package `animate` to animate the sequence of PDF (Acrobat will be necessary to play the animation). I don't see other solution, let alone that that SVG doesn't seem to be standard.

Comment: @alfC SVG 1.1 is a W3 standard and [supports the animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html). SVG 1.1 is a W3 standard and supports the animations. If you forget - for a minute - Inkscape, we are talking about a pure XML code. The question is the same: is there, in LaTeX, a way to insert a SVG 1.1 code and preserve the animations?

Comment: Good to know. Does it also support interactivity (clicks)? Do you know a graphical editor to the animate SVG? Sorry that I can't help you with your question.

Comment: Remember: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=svg+animation+editor).

Comment: Now, *I* want LaTeX to support SVG animations. :)

Comment: @alfC BTW, `animate` can now export to animated SVG. (Though not import, as asked here.)

Comment: @AlexG, are you talking about the `export` option at the end of section 4 of the manual http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf ? do you need to convert from PDF (multipage) to SVG get the animation? with which tool?

Comment: @alfC: No. Exporting to JS driven animated SVG is a new feature, added about 10 days ago ;). Same look and feel (control buttons, interactivity) as PDF animations. Can be embedded in HTML or viewed as standalone files in a Web browser. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919 for a trivial example and click on the image to load the SVG.

Comment: @AlexG, excellent, `dvisvgm` (which I didn't know) was the answer. Congratulations for the new feature.

Comment: How do you want to print an animated PDF?

Comment: @henri The same way you would print an MP4, I suppose. ;-)

Comment: @Henri, I would like obtain a interactive PDF. As the example in the Wiki.

Comment: PDF anims are frame-based, while SMIL-type SVG animations animate object properties, such as position, scale, colour, transparency. An external programme is needed to convert such into image sequences. I don't know whether Inkscape (or other software) is able to do this.