# Is it possible to have a "slide show" embedded within a document?

Tags: presentations

I am writing a paper that contains figures, and I would like one of these figures to be interactive. That is, rather than show a static figure in the paper, I want to display a "dynamic" figure (in the PDF) that the reader can click through using hyperlinks that look like left and right arrows. Basically, the idea is to embed a miniature slide show *inside* my paper (as I understand it, Beamer forces the entire paper to be one big presentation), where each slide shows a different figure that has some relationship to the figure preceding it in the deck.

I saw [this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/) thing, but all of the examples are sophisticated, which makes their code difficult to adapt. I just want to show a series of JPEGs. Is this possible?

Comment: You might [try these answers.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152358/animations-in-latex) You can also include a PDF inside your document.

Comment: Thanks for the link. They all seem to suggest (i) methods to create animations (e.g., gif) from a pdf file to be used outside of the pdf, or (ii) methods to run a gif or other non-interactive animation in the PDF. I am interested in creating a controllable, interactive animation that runs based on hyperlinks in the PDF

Comment: The usual trick is to repeat everything on the page except the animation, or whatever it is you want to change.  Then you just switch pages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I do not intend on going through the paper with a live audience. Rather, I want it to be indistinguishable from any other published PDF paper you might come across (e.g., this one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.12812.pdf), except that its figures are interactive.

Comment: Are you sure that is not how they did it?  How could you tell the difference?  Even if you expand the PDF as an ASCII file (which it is, albeit with encoded blocks), what would you look for?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Not sure what you mean by "they". If you mean the sophisticated animations I mentioned in my post (https://texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/wankel-motor.tex), these literally contain clickable arrows (right and left) in a single-page PDF.