# Animating equations using latex

Tags: overleaf, animations, animate

I want to make an animation with equations such that one repeats after other. Say I have, x+y=2 and x-y=1 then I want to make an animation such that I get first

x+y=2 then it vanishes and

x-y=1 appears in the next line.
I am familiar with latex, can I do that with latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). If you want to use this within a beamer presentation, there would be better controllable commands for that, than an animation. What ist your document type?

Comment: Perhaps [this older thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152358/animations-in-latex) might be helpful, with code examples for different kinds of animations (in-PDF, GIF export, etc.).

Comment: There are several packages that can do this. `Beamer` does it natively with the overlay commands. The `animate` package can do this as well as the `ocgx2` package. Not forgetting the `pgf` package which can make animations in `svg` format!
You are spoilt for choice.