# Tikz Fractal - Uniform Cantor Set

Tags: tikz-pgf, lindenmayer

To go along with my other fractals: [Tikz Fractal - Cantor Dust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380025/tikz-fractal-cantor-dust) and [Tikz Fractal - Menger Sponge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383399/tikz-fractal-menger-sponge), which you lovely people have helped my create, I would like to construct a "uniform Cantor set".

The construction is as follows:

Take the unit interval [0,1] and at each stage replace each interval with (a fixed number) n intervals of length less than |I|/n, where |I| is the length of the interval, and where an end point of the each of the subintervals coincides with the end point of its 'father' interval.

Here is a picture to try to make my shoddy explanation a little clearer:
[image]

The standard middle third Cantor set is where n=2 and |I|=1/3:
[image]

Short of working out all of the length and spacings, how can I construct this "automatically"? My thinking is that I should use a linedenmayer system but I have not done this for line segments before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `lindenmayer system`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cantor set}{
  \rule{F -> FfF}
  \rule{f -> fff}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \order in {0,...,4}
    \draw[yshift=-\order*10pt]  l-system[l-system={cantor set, axiom=F, order=\order, step=100pt/(3^\order)}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A Cantor set with a division into three bits is a trivial extension of the existing one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cantor set}{
  \rule{F -> FfFfF}
  \rule{f -> fffff}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \order in {0,...,4}
    \draw[yshift=-\order*10pt]  l-system[l-system={cantor set, axiom=F, order=\order, step=100pt/(5^\order)}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks really good, thank you. Could you briefly explain your code? (how do I make it into 3 equally spaced sections?)

Comment: So the `F` are drawn, due to `axiom=F`, and all others words of the grammar (here `f`) take up blank space ?

Comment: I think this is the droid I am looking for, thanks. I will have a play with it.

Comment: Ah sorry, just looked at the doc : `F` and `f` are library keywords for `draw a line` and `take up space`. The `axiom=F` option sets the initial state, the root from which next steps are iteratively expanded following the system's rules. (By the way, very elegant code ! It would be a nice example for the TikZ manual.)

Comment: Is there any way to get it so the gaps in between are not the same length as the lngths of the intervals?

Comment: @JSharpee No, then it's not fractal anymore.

Comment: @JSharpee You could try this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151278 but I don't think it will be a clean solution.

Comment: @HenriMenke, it is still a fractal. It's known as the Uniform Cantor set. The spaces don't have to be the same as the intervals. In fact, the spaces (or intervals) don't have to be the same as each other at all. So you can have things that look really messy, but are still considered fractals.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Cantor set` decoration from the `decorations.fractals` library.  An example is given in the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set,very thick]
  \draw decorate{ (0,0) -- (3,0) };
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-.5) -- (3,-.5) }};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1) -- (3,-1) }}};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1.5) -- (3,-1.5) }}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution based on boxes and rules:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\gen}[1]{%
  \hrule height 5mm\relax
  \ifnum#1>0 %
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  {%
    \kern5mm\relax
    \hbox to \hsize{%
      \vbox{%
        \hsize=.3333\hsize
        \gen{\numexpr#1-1}%
      }\hfill
      \vbox{%
        \hsize=.3333\hsize
        \gen{\numexpr#1-1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\genpic}[2]{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1}%
    \gen{#2}%
  \end{minipage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \genpic{\linewidth}{8}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is obviously much more idiomatic than my approach `:D`

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Lindenmayer systems, but this is easy to do using TeX recursivity.

### The output

the PNG below doesn't look great but the PDF is alright.

The code starts getting slow from `n=11` or so on.

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=20,yscale=2]
  \def\gen|#1|
  {
    \if 0#1
      \path[fill] (0,0) rectangle (1,.8) ;
    \else
      \begin{scope}[xscale=1/3,yshift=-1cm]
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{#1-1}
        \gen|\k|
        \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
          \gen|\k|
        \end{scope}
      \end{scope}
    \fi
  }

  \foreach \k in {0,...,11}
  {
    \gen|\k|
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```